# C# show custom error from Oracle procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, exception

```
create or replace procedure naujas_veiksmai(
vartotojas number,
knyga number,
kiekis number,
grazinta VARCHAR2,
tipas varchar2,
error_msg out varchar2
)

is
begin
insert into veiksmai values(vt_id_seq.nextval,vartotojas,knyga,kiekis,tipas,sysdate,TO_DATE(grazinta,'YYYY-MM-DD'));
exception 
when OTHERS THEN error_msg := 'Irasant ivyko klaida'; 
end;
```

This is procedure that must return custom error to program.

C# code:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "naujas_veiksmai";

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    OdbcParameter param = new OdbcParameter();

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("vartotojas", OracleType.Number).Value = vartotojas;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("knyga", OracleType.Number).Value = knyga;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("kiekis", OracleType.Number).Value = kiekis;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("grazinta", OracleType.VarChar).Value = grazinti;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("tipas", OracleType.VarChar).Value = tipas;
                        OracleParameter op = new OracleParameter("error_msg", OracleType.VarChar);
                        op.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        op.Size = 200;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(op);


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt(0);
```

Program not showing any errors from oracle, insert was not executed and I know that must be exception.

What is wrong in procedure or in oracle code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already told the stored procedure that, if any exception is thrown, write a message to the `error_msg` parameter.

Check the value of that parameter after executing the stored procedure:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

var errorMessage = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["error_msg"].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

**It is not good idea to add additional `out` parameter for  sending exception message to the back-end.**

If you want to see your exception message in try/catch block , then you must use  `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`.
The `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` built-in is used for just a single scenario: if you need to communicate an application-specific error back to the user.

```
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20003, 'CUSTOM EXCEPTION MESSAGE');
```

and it will throw exactly same exception in this statement:

```
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string customMessage = ex.Message;
}
```

**Update**:

```
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20003, 'CUSTOM EXCEPTION MESSAGE');
```